# Find String and Replace between 2 Strings - Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that I would like to find within it all the words between Description  and   and replace the words so that they are just 255 characters long. If the words are less than 255 characters it does nothing, if it is more than 255 characters it is to truncate the words. I used a regular expression, only words are caught outside the range defined by me.

I am the folowing regular expression:

```cs
(?<=<Name>Description<\/Name><Value>)(?<Text>.{0,255}).*?(?=<\/Value>)
```

The code is C#.

I have a C# script that does the folowing:

```
            string strFile = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\FINAL.xml");
            string pattern = @"(?<=<Name>Description<\/Name><Value>)(?<Text>.{0,255}).*?(?=<\/Value>)";
            string result = Regex.Replace(strFile, pattern, "${Text}");
            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\FINAL.xml", result);
```

For example: https://regex101.com/r/Etfpol/5

Comment: You may wish to use a XML/HTML parser rather than parsing XML/HTML with regex.

Comment: I just wanted to replace the sentences above 255 characters within what I asked for. If there is an alternative to what I'm doing.

I gave a C# script that does the folowing;

                string strFile = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\FINAL.xml");
                string pattern = @"(?<=<Name>Description<\/Name><Value>)(?<Text>.{0,255}).*?(?=<\/Value>)";
                string result = Regex.Replace(strFile, pattern, "${Text}");
                File.WriteAllText(@"D:\FINAL.xml", result);

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea, but your idea, your pc, ... (in general you shouldn't use Regexes to "parse" xml or html, bad things could happen/will happen, perhaps not today but tomorrow or the day after)

```
string pattern = @"(?<=<Name>Description</Name><Value>)([^<]*)(?=</Value>)";
const int maxLength = 255
string result = Regex.Replace(strFile, pattern, x => x.Value.Length > maxLength ? x.Value.Remove(maxLength) : x.Value);
```

You need a `MatchEvaluator`, a method that receives the match and calculates a replacement.

Mmmh... You can even do without a `MatchEvaluator`...

```
string pattern = @"(?<=<Name>Description</Name><Value>)([^<]{0,255})([^<]*)(?=</Value>)";
string result = Regex.Replace(strFile, pattern, "$1");
```

Comment: I agree with your synopsis that "...don't use regex to parse xml", but disagree with the *Doom and gloom* supposition; it would be better served to simply state that using an XML or HTML parser would, in the long run require less code/maintenance for a majority of tasks of this nature. :-)

Comment: DOOOOOOOOM! :-)